# What is causing the light flex to go black and the fitting to brown and brittle?

Tags: light-fixture

There are two such light fittings in the same room. One is perfectly fine, but the other consistently has the same problem even when replaced. Both the fitting and the cable started out white.  Over time, the cable has become a dirty black and feels like it has a coating.

The lampshades are open and thus not containing the heat from bulbs. Please see the photo showing the issue. I am not sure if it is relevant, but it is nearer the window fitted with vents than the other.

What could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: Probably not dusting.  Air moisture plus dust over time will build up.  Turn off breaker for it and carefully wipe it down with a damp cloth, let dry then turn power back on.  The lamp fixture should be replacing if it is brittle.  Some plastics do not last over time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Usually too much heat over a long time.  This is most likely to be caused by high wattage incandescent lamps (perhaps 100W), or enclosed light fittings with insufficient ventilation.